# ДедЫ и дЕды

Tags: фонетика

Интересно, допустимы оба варианты или только "дЕды"? А если речь идет не о предках, а о стариках? Тоже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь идёт о стариках, или предках то только дЕды, а вот старослужащие в армии - уже дедЫ

Comment: Возможен как разговорный вариант дедЫ (о стариках) в устной речи: Да сидели там древние дедЫ...

Comment: Поинтересуюсь, а **"бабЫ"** в России где-нибудь говорят?

На отдельный вопрос это не тянет, потому напишу в комментариях.

Comment: @Nikolja, говорят. Правда по отношению опять же к деду. По Далю:

 бабА или бабАй муж., татар., новорос., оренб. дед, дедушка, старик; иногда ·в·знач. детского пугала.
| астрах. большой, становой якорь. Детей пугают и бабайкою, старухою, и тут сходятся производства от бабы и от бабая

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.